# Raster disappears when pan or zoom

Tags: qgis, raster, visualisation

I'm having the following problem in QGIS 2.12.0.
When I load a raster, this disappear when I pan or zoom in or out the image. If I try to do some actions three four times, it appears again. It seems there's no logic, just happen almost all the time the image is moved. 
Anyone has an idea of what can be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @F.Cian! Can you mention which platform (Windows, Linux etc.) you are using please? A bug which sounds similar to what you are describing has been reported here: [Bug report #12522](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/12522).

Comment: What format is the raster? How big is it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have *scale -dependent visibility* (translated from Dutch) checked in the layer-properties? This makes the layer(s) only visible from a certain scale. Maybe this is the issue.
If it is a large image this sometimes can create view complications. You can *build pyramids* in the layer properties to make the file easier accessible. This makes the file only "show" the necessary data on a particular scale. 
Hope this helps!